# What does 'yield' keyword do in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, yield

What does the `yield` keyword actually do in Dart?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`yield` adds a value to the output stream of the surrounding `async*` function. It's like `return`, but doesn't terminate the function.

See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators

```
Stream asynchronousNaturalsTo(n) async* {
  int k = 0;
  while (k < n) yield k++;
}
```

> When the yield statement executes, it adds the result of evaluating its expression to the stream. It doesn’t necessarily suspend (though in the current implementations it does).

Comment: `It's like return, but doesn't terminate the function.`

What a perfect way to explain this without going into the weeds..  Thank you.

That said, if you want to go into the weeds on this topic Tokenyet has a great answer below.

Comment: Perfect, plus one, for short complete answer and comparison

Comment: One important thing to mention: In `async*` functions `yield` *halts* execution of current task and switches it to caller (`await for` loop). Not keeping it in mind might lead you into very weird execution stalls. Couple of gists to highlight potential problem: [non-stalling example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=74366082d24030fe43cd8f5ada424e94), [stalling example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f4363c73fd2ba0d0a4fb38e7c0dac68c)

Comment: Last note is no longer present in the documentation, now it clearly says `An async* function automatically pauses at a yield statement while the stream subscription is paused.`

Answer (score 133):

The accepted answer's link is broken, [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators) is an official link about `async* sync* yield* yield`.

If you have some experiences with other languages, you might stuck at these keywords. Here are some *tips* for getting over keywords.

1. `async* sync* yield* yield` are called **generator functions**. You might use these mostly in **Bloc pattern**.
2. `async*` is also a `async`, you could use **Asynchronous** as usual.
3. `sync*` cannot be used as `sync`, you will receive the error that noticed **"The modifier sync must be followed by a star"**.
4. `yield` and `yield*` can only be used with **generator functions** (`async*` `sync*`).

And there are four combinations.

1. `async* yield` will return a `Stream<dynamic>`.

```dart
Stream<int> runToMax(int n) async* {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    yield i;
    i++;
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 300));
  }
}
```

2. `async* yield*` will call a function and return `Stream<dynamic>`.

```dart
Stream<int> countDownFrom(int n) async* {
  if (n > 0) {
    yield n;
    yield* countDownFrom(n - 1);
  }
}
```

3. `sync* yield`  will return a `Iterable<dynamic>`.

```dart
Iterable<int> genIterates(int max) sync* {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < max) {
    yield i;
    i++;
  }
}
```

4. `sync* yield*` will call a function and return `Iterable<dynamic>`.

```dart
Iterable<int> countDownFrom(int n) sync* {
  if (n > 0) {
    yield n;
    yield* countDownFrom(n - 1);
  }
}
```

If there are any errors, please leave a comment to correct the answer.

Comment: I fixed the link in my answer.

Comment: I think the correct answer for the yield* is, delegating to another generator rather than call a function. yield* simply delegates to the another generator which means the current generator stops, another generator takes the job until it stops producing. After that one stops producing values, the main generator resumes producing its own values.

Comment: @mirkancal That is such a clear explanation that it should go into an answer, not just a comment.

Answer (score 17):

I think the correct answer for the yield* is, delegating to another generator rather than call a function. yield* simply delegates to the another generator which means the current generator stops, another generator takes the job until it stops producing. After that one stops producing values, the main generator resumes producing its own values.

Thanks @András Szepesházi for encouraging me to post this comment as an answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. To add to your answer, `yield*` is useful for: A. refactor generator code by nesting multiple generators B. recursive generator.

Comment: [If your generator is recursive, you can improve its performance by using yield*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators)

Answer (score 3):

The `yield` statement can be used only in generator's functions.
The generator's function generates data items in natural way (as calculated, received from outside, predefined values etc).
When next data item is ready then the `yield` statement send this item into data sequence which is essentially the generation result of the function.
The data sequence can be synchronous or asyncronous.
In Dart language the synchronous data sequence means the instance of `Iterable`.
The asynchronous data sequence means the instance of `Stream`.

P.S.
Generator functions can generate data items indefinitely until the function returns.
But unlike normal functions, the result (the data sequence) will be returned immediately after the function call and can be used immediately.
The end of the data sequence, in this case, can be reached only when generator function will be terminated (successfully or by failure).