# flutter async call doesn't run asynchronously in initState()

Tags: flutter, future

I'm calling async function in initState(),
but the system actually waits the result of async function.
Could anyone tell me why?

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<int> _f;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
    print('executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
    _f = getFuture();
    print('executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
  }

  Future<int> getFuture() async {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 1000000000) {
      i++;
    }
    return i;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("test")),
      body: FutureBuilder<int>(
        future: _f,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Center(child: Text("snapshot: ${snapshot.data}"));
              break;
            default:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
I/flutter (22058): executed in 0:00:00.000384
I/flutter (22058): executed in 0:00:04.536278
```

Comment: Maybe using yield should help. This answer explains it well https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173833/955739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Future` function is made to return a `Future` object asynchronously. Which means executing a statement of code once that will take a much longer time, for example getting json object from an api, than the usual time required for a normal statement, for example a declaration of a variable.

However, you are executing a normal statement, that requires milliseconds to run, a `1000000000` times. That will result in a **longer execution time** which was built up by the milliseconds of each execution.

Even though it is a `Future` function, it is not returning a `Future` object or variable, so it is not asynchronous.