# Evaluate a FutureProvider inside the StreamProvider callback

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a stream provider that depends on a request to resolve. However the execution steps put at the first `await` statement, causing the response to be null. Which throws an error

The request provider

```dart
final postProvider = FutureProvider.family.autoDispose(
  (ref, Tuple2<String?, Map<dynamic, dynamic>?> info) async {
    var path = info.item1 ?? '';
    var payload = info.item2;

    final url = backendUrl().replace(path: path);
    return await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-FIREBASE_TOKEN':
            await ref.read(authProvider).currentUser!.getIdToken() //this is where execution steps out
      },
      body: payload != null ? jsonEncode(payload) : null,
    );
  },
);
```

the StreamProvider:

```dart
final chatProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final chatId = ref.watch(chatIdProvider);

  if (chatId == null) {
    final resp = ref
        .watch(postProvider(const Tuple2('create-chat', null)))
        .value!; //this evaluates to null.

    ref.read(chatIdProvider.notifier).state = jsonDecode(resp.body)['chat_id'];
  }

  final uid = ref.watch(userStreamProvider).value!.uid;

  return ref.read(docRefProvider('${uid}_chats/$chatId')).snapshots();
});
```

I can't use the future from the FutureProvider because that would require me to have an `async` callback, which would not return a Future rather than a Stream. How do I work around this?

Comment: If you use a generated family provider, a lot of that nonsense with Tuple2 goes away.  You should look in to that.

Comment: Refactoring is not a priority right now.

Comment: nesting awaits essentially, right?  Just have to use a FutureBuilder, and then you can do the Streambuilder...or that's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is try and use yield, like the below example.
The `if` block checks if the `chatId` is `null`, and if it is, it waits for the postProvider to resolve by using `await ref.watch(postProvider(const Tuple2('create-chat', null)).last)`.

```
final chatProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) async* {
  final chatId = ref.watch(chatIdProvider);

  if (chatId == null) {
    final resp = await ref.watch(postProvider(const Tuple2('create-chat', null)).last);

    ref.read(chatIdProvider.notifier).state = jsonDecode(resp.body)['chat_id'];
  }

  final uid = ref.watch(userStreamProvider).value!.uid;

  yield* ref.read(docRefProvider('${uid}_chats/$chatId')).snapshots();
});
```

more on that here https://dart.dev/language/functions#generators
and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173833/5666202

and the `last` on the `resp` returns a Future that returns the last emitted value from the provider, which is what you seem to need in this case

Comment: I decided to put all the future logic on a button call back. If anyone has tried this solution, please mention it and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: This is helpful as an extension for official doc, thanks!